# Why is invoking a method on the same line as awaiting it considered asynchronous?

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm looking at the examples on http://www.dotnetperls.com/async to better understand async/await, but the following is confusing to me:

I understand why the example below is considered asynchronous.  *HandleFileAsync* is invoked, the *Console.WriteLine* call is made, then we await the completion of *task* before proceeding.

```
static async void ProcessDataAsync()
{
     // Start the HandleFile method.
     Task<int> task = HandleFileAsync("C:\\enable1.txt");

     // Control returns here before HandleFileAsync returns.
     // ... Prompt the user.
     Console.WriteLine("Please wait patiently " +
         "while I do something important.");

     // Wait for the HandleFile task to complete.
     // ... Display its results.
     int x = await task;
     Console.WriteLine("Count: " + x);
}
```

However in the following example, we *await* a call to *Task.Run* which runs an action:

```
static async void Example()
{
     // This method runs asynchronously.
     int t = await Task.Run(() => Allocate());
     Console.WriteLine("Compute: " + t);
}
```

So, if we are *awaiting* the completion of Task.Run here, what exactly is happening asynchronously? I thought it becomes a blocking call once as soon as we *await* the subsequent task's execution to complete, which, in this case is invoked on the same line.

What am I missing?

Comment: `HandleFileAsync` is not invoked until you `await` it at the end, so your snippets are essentially identical in terms of async functionality. You're simply taking a pointer to the task at the top. However, I believe you're misunderstand what `async` does. It is only asynchronous in terms of not blocking the main context thread (or UI thread for GUI applications). The code will still run in order, line by line - `HandleFileAsync` does not run in parallel with the rest of the code in `ProcessDataAsync`.

Comment: @Rob: Not at all. `HandleFileAsync` is invoked  at the first line of `ProcessDataAsync`.

Comment: @bulletblue: I agree with Eric Lippert that the dotnetperls tutorial is confusing and somewhat misleading. I have [an async intro of my own](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) that may help you.

Comment: @StephenCleary What is the expected behavior if the line `Task<int> task = HandleFileAsync(...)` runs but task is never awaited? Is HandleFileAsync executed but we just don’t ever get the result? So if we do not care about the result but only the execution can we choose not to await?

Comment: @Howiecamp: Most of the time "fire and forget" is a mistake. Are you sure you don't care about the result? You don't need to know if it fails? (Exceptions would be placed on the task, which your code would ignore). You don't need to know when it's completed, so your code knows it's safe to exit your program?

Comment: @StephenCleary Makes total sense to me now.  Thanks for helping to crystalize this for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I thought it becomes a blocking call once as soon as we await the subsequent task's execution to complete, which, in this case is invoked on the same line. What am I missing?

Your belief is false; that's what you're missing.  "await" means "return now, go run something else while we are **asynchronously waiting**, and when the result is available, come back here."

Fetching the result of the task does what you think await does.  We would not have had to invent await if all it did was synchronously fetch the result of the task! It *asynchronously* fetches the result of the task.

While we're at it, this comment is wrong:

```
// Control returns here before HandleFileAsync returns.
```

How could that possibly be?  **HandleFileAsync returned a task!**  How did control get to that point **with a task in hand** if HandleFileAsync did not return? Of course it returned.

And this comment is misleading:

```
// Wait for the HandleFile task to complete.
```

That should be **asynchronously wait** for the task to complete.  By asynchronously waiting, remember, we mean "return now, go run more work, and when the task is complete, resume at this point with the result in hand."

I would find a better tutorial if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

what exactly is happening asynchronously?
consider this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static volatile uint i;
        static uint Test()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            i = 2; //uint.MaxValue;
            while (i-- > 0) { }
            return i;
        }

        static bool done;
        static async void Example()
        {
            var t = await Task.Run(() => Test());
            Console.WriteLine("result: " + t);
            done = true;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Example();
            Console.WriteLine("wait: Control returns here before Example() returns ");
            while (!done) { }
            Console.WriteLine("done ");
        }
    }
}
```

the `Example();`  itself is happening asynchronously. 
so if you remove `while (!done) { }`
the program exits before `Example()` finishes.
I hope this helps.